# Can't remove items from NSPopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to remove items from NSPopUpButton but it seems like this is not working

I have tried:

```
[self.myMenu removeAllItems];
```

And also:

```
    NSInteger items = [_myMenu numberOfItems];

    for (NSInteger i = (items -1) ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        [self.myMenu removeItemAtIndex:i];
    }
```

But if I check the count of myMenu (NSPopUpButton) in the console I get this:

p [_myMenu numberOfItems]
(NSInteger) $3 = 0

but I check the NSPopUpButton on my application window I still have all the items. Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong of if is a trick to remove the items?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSPopupButton provides 3 API's for removing items.

1) removeAllItems
2) removeItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title
3) removeItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index

In your case , no need access the menu. You can directly call like this
[popupButton removeItemAtIndex:0];